# How to make LongPressGesture and scrolling in ScrollView work together at the same time in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture, tap

Let's imagine, here is a ScrollView with some elements and I want to make some actions (e.g. changing of color) on long tap on these elements. But also I want to make possible to scroll this view.

Here is an example:

[image: Example of scrolling and long taps together]

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextBox: View {
  var text: String
  var color: Color
  @GestureState private var isLongPressure: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    let longTap = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.3)
      .updating($isLongPressure) { state, newState, transaction in
        newState = state
        transaction.animation = .easeOut(duration: 0.2)
      }
    
    Text(text)
      .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
      .background(isLongPressure ? .white : color)
      .simultaneousGesture(longTap)
  }
}

struct TestGestures: View {
    var body: some View {
      ScrollView {
        TextBox(text: "Test 1", color: .red)
        TextBox(text: "Test 2", color: .green)
        TextBox(text: "Test 3", color: .blue)
        TextBox(text: "Test 4", color: .red)
        TextBox(text: "Test 5", color: .green)
        TextBox(text: "Test 6", color: .blue)
      }
    }
}

struct TestGestures_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestGestures()
    }
}
```

So, if I comment `.simultaneousGesture(longTap)` – scrolling works, but if I uncomment it – scrolling stopped work.

P.S.: I've tried to add `onTapGesture` before adding longTap and it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update:**

Thanks for the solution by [@nickreps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12053724/nickreps):

[image: Fixed scrolling and long tap]

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextBox: View {
  var text: String
  var color: Color
  @GestureState private var isLongPressure: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    let longTap = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.3)
      .updating($isLongPressure) { value, state, transaction in
        state = value
        transaction.animation = .easeOut(duration: 0.2)
      }
    
    Text(text)
      .frame(width: 400, height: 200)
      .background(isLongPressure ? .white : color)
      .delaysTouches(for: 0.01) {
        //some code here, if needed
      }
      .gesture(longTap)
  }
}

struct TestGestures: View {
    var body: some View {
      ScrollView {
        TextBox(text: "Test 1", color: .red)
        TextBox(text: "Test 2", color: .green)
        TextBox(text: "Test 3", color: .blue)
        TextBox(text: "Test 4", color: .red)
        TextBox(text: "Test 5", color: .green)
        TextBox(text: "Test 6", color: .blue)
      }
    }
}

extension View {
    func delaysTouches(for duration: TimeInterval = 0.25, onTap action: @escaping () -> Void = {}) -> some View {
        modifier(DelaysTouches(duration: duration, action: action))
    }
}

fileprivate struct DelaysTouches: ViewModifier {
    @State private var disabled = false
    @State private var touchDownDate: Date? = nil
    
    var duration: TimeInterval
    var action: () -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            content
        }
        .buttonStyle(DelaysTouchesButtonStyle(disabled: $disabled, duration: duration, touchDownDate: $touchDownDate))
        .disabled(disabled)
    }
}

fileprivate struct DelaysTouchesButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Binding var disabled: Bool
    var duration: TimeInterval
    @Binding var touchDownDate: Date?
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed, perform: handleIsPressed)
    }
    
    private func handleIsPressed(isPressed: Bool) {
        if isPressed {
            let date = Date()
            touchDownDate = date
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + max(duration, 0)) {
                if date == touchDownDate {
                    disabled = true
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        disabled = false
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            touchDownDate = nil
            disabled = false
        }
    }
}


struct TestGestures_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestGestures()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working by utilizing a button rather than a TextView. Although this does directly utilize the code you provided, you should be able to modify some pieces to have it meet your needs (I can help with this, if needed!)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollTest: View {
    let testData = [1]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            AnimatedButtonView(color: .red, text: "Test 1")
            AnimatedButtonView(color: .green, text: "Test 2")
            AnimatedButtonView(color: .blue, text: "Test 3")
        }
    }
}



struct AnimatedButtonView: View {
    @GestureState var isDetectingLongPress = false
    let color: Color
    let text: String
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.5, style: .continuous)
                .fill(color)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
                .padding(25)
                .scaleEffect(!isDetectingLongPress ? 1.0 : 0.875)
                .brightness(!isDetectingLongPress ? 0.0 : -0.125)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.125), value: isDetectingLongPress)
            Text(text)
        }
        
        .delaysTouches(for: 0.01) {
            //some code here, if needed
        }
        .gesture(
            LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
                .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { currentState, gestureState,
                    transaction in
                    gestureState = currentState
                    transaction.animation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 2.0)
                }
                .onEnded { finished in
                    print("gesture ended")
                })
        
    }
}

extension View {
    func delaysTouches(for duration: TimeInterval = 0.25, onTap action: @escaping () -> Void = {}) -> some View {
        modifier(DelaysTouches(duration: duration, action: action))
    }
}

fileprivate struct DelaysTouches: ViewModifier {
    @State private var disabled = false
    @State private var touchDownDate: Date? = nil
    
    var duration: TimeInterval
    var action: () -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            content
        }
        .buttonStyle(DelaysTouchesButtonStyle(disabled: $disabled, duration: duration, touchDownDate: $touchDownDate))
        .disabled(disabled)
    }
}

fileprivate struct DelaysTouchesButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Binding var disabled: Bool
    var duration: TimeInterval
    @Binding var touchDownDate: Date?
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed, perform: handleIsPressed)
    }
    
    private func handleIsPressed(isPressed: Bool) {
        if isPressed {
            let date = Date()
            touchDownDate = date
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + max(duration, 0)) {
                if date == touchDownDate {
                    disabled = true
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        disabled = false
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            touchDownDate = nil
            disabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the exact context, but you could add a condition so your `LongPressGesture` only triggers an action when gesture is not being used for scrolling.

```
let longTap = LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.3)
  .updating($isLongPressure) { value, state, transaction in
    if value {
      state = true
      transaction.animation = .easeOut(duration: 0.2)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but there is an error "Value of type 'Transaction' has no member 'isDisabled'".

Comment: I've updated the code with an alternative, try this one instead.

Comment: It still won't work because type of value is Bool, so I get an error:

Cannot convert value of type 'LongPressGesture.Value' (aka 'Bool') to expected argument type 'HoverPhase'

But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of @nickreps solution, but a bit shorter:

```
struct MyView : View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView { VStack { ForEach(0..<40) { _ in Item() } } }
    }
    
}

struct Item : View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .frame(height: 100)
            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
            .yieldTouches() // <- this solves gestures conflict
            .gesture(
                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1, maximumDistance: 10)
                        .onEnded { _ in print("hello!") }
             )
    }
    
}

public extension View {
    
    func yieldTouches() -> some View { modifier(YieldTouches()) }
    
}

private struct YieldTouches : ViewModifier {
    
    @State private var disabled = false
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .disabled(disabled)
            .onTapGesture { onMain { disabled = true; onMain { disabled = false } } }
    }
    
    private func onMain(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) { DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: action) }
    
}
```